# Change the signs of the elements in a matrix if all rows contain at least one negative element

Tags: python, python-3.5

I want to check if all the rows of the matrix contain at least one negative element. If so, change the signs of all the elements of the matrix.

Here is my attempt, but this way just changes the sign of the negative elements:

```
matrix = [[5, -6, 2], [7, -2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j] < 0:
             print(matrix[i][j]*(-1))
```

Comment: Maybe removing the `if matrix[i][j] < 0:` condition?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT:

So first you can check if matrix contains at least one negative element, then change sign of all elements.

```
matrix = [[5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]

hasNegativeElement = False

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j] < 0:
            hasNegativeElement = True
            break

if hasNegativeElement:
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            matrix[i][j] *= (-1)
```

Comment: But the condition is: if all the rows of the matrix contain at least one negative element.   If so, change the signs of all the elements of the matrix are reversed.

Comment: Thanks for minus :D. I know it's not the shortest answer, but maybe the clearest one.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me. I didn't, I can not vote

Comment: I know, i mean someone who did this. No problem for answer, i will post shortest one, maybe you will be interested in this.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it very easy with [`numpy`](http://numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
In [108]: np.array(matrix) * -1
Out[108]: 
array([[-5,  6, -2],
       [-7, -2, -3],
       [-8, -4,  9]])
```

Or if you want a list at the end you could use [`tolist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method:

```
In [124]: (np.array(matrix) * -1).tolist()
Out[124]: [[-5, 6, -2], [-7, -2, -3], [-8, -4, 9]]
```

Comment: This forgets to check whether all rows contain at least one negative element ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
allRowsNegative = True;
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    foundNegative = False;
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        foundNegative = (foundNegative or matrix[i][j] < 0);
    allRowsNegative = (allRowsNegative and foundNegative);

if allRowsNegative:
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            print(matrix[i][j]*(-1));
else:
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            print(matrix[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

non numpy solution:

```
>>> matrix = [[5, -6, 2], [7, -2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]
>>> if all(any(x < 0 for x in sub) for sub in matrix):
...     result = [[-x for x in sub] for sub in matrix]
... 
>>> result
[[-5, 6, -2], [-7, 2, -3], [-8, -4, 9]]
```

numpy solution

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = [[5, -6, 2], [7, -2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]
>>> m_arr = np.array(matrix)
>>> if np.all(np.any(m_arr < 0, axis=1)):
...     result = (m_arr*(-1)).tolist()
... 
>>> result
[[-5, 6, -2], [-7, 2, -3], [-8, -4, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check every row with `np.any` for a negative element which would give an array and you can then check if all of them turned out to have a negative element via `np.all`. If so reverse the sign of the matrix.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]])

if np.all(np.any(A<0,axis=1)):
    A *= -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that comes to my mind :

```
m = [[5,-6, 2], [7, -2, 3], [8, 4, -9], [2 , 4 ,6]]

for i in range(len(m)):
    flag = False
    for y in m[i]:
        if(y<0):
            flag = True
            break
    if (flag == True):
        for j in range(len(m[i])):
            m[i][j] = -1 * m[i][j]


print (m)           # [[-5, 6, -2], [-7, 2, -3], [-8, -4, 9], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to check whether all rows contain a negative number (assuming your matrix is at least 1x1, not empty):

```
   max(map(min, matrix)) < 0
```

So overall:

```
if max(map(min, matrix)) < 0:
    matrix[:] = [[-x for x in row] for row in matrix]
```